# How to Group and Order in a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to group & order by in a query builder expression. The following query gets me close to what i want but the order by does not appear to be working.

what i have is an object that has unique ids but some will have a common versionId.  I would like to get the last edited item of the same versionId. So only one item per version id and i want it to be the last edited one.

```
IQueryable<Item> result = DataContext.Items.Where(x => (x.ItemName.Contains(searchKeyword) ||
                                  x.ItemDescription.Contains(searchKeyword))
                                  .GroupBy(y => y.VersionId)
                                  .Select(z => z.OrderByDescending(item => item.LastModifiedDateTime).FirstOrDefault());
```

**Edit:** I don't really care about the order of the result set, i really just care about what item within the grouping is returned.  I want to make sure that the last edited Item within a versionId group is return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `z` parameter contains the individual group objects.

By calling `OrderBy` inside of `Select`, you're ordering the items in each group, but not the groups themselves.

You need to also call `OrderBy` after `Select`, like this:

```
.Select(z.OrderByDescending(item => item.LastModifiedDateTime).FirstOrDefault())
.Where(item => item != null)
.OrderByDescending(item => item.LastModifiedTime)
```

Comment: I'm not so worried about the order of the different versionIds(the outer orderby), i'm more concerned within a given versionId.  My First query does not seem to apply the order to the items within that grouping based on versionId.